# How to fit a number of inputs on one line in parent div?

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I am trying to put 5 inputs on one line. Simple, I thought. I have a parent div which has some margin on the left and right. I've put inputs with 20% width inside (5 x 20 = 100%). But the last input goes to the bottom, without a reason? Does someone knows why and how to solve this?

```html
<body style="background: orange;">
  <div style="margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px;"> 
    <form>
      <input style="width: 20%; padding:0; margin:0;" type="text">
      <input style="width: 20%; padding:0; margin:0;" type="text">
      <input style="width: 20%; padding:0; margin:0;" type="text">
      <input style="width: 20%; padding:0; margin:0;" type="text">
      <input style="width: 20%; padding:0; margin:0;" type="text">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: border and white space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to do it with **flexbox**.

```css
form {
  display: flex;
}

input {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</form>
```

**Why your example didn't work is because:**

- `<input>` is inline level, it also has default padding and borders set from browser default stylesheet.
- There is also white space in between the input boxes, they will be rendered as well.

To fix it with your original approach, you can do:

```css
form {
  font-size: 0; /* remove white space */
}

input {
  font-size: 16px; /* reset font size */
  width: 20%;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* make border and padding part of width and height */
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</form>
```

You can also **float** the input boxes so white space won't get rendered.

```css
form:after { /* clear floats */
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

input {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: While this is the best answer for how to do it in the modern web, it would probably be useful to the asker if you also explained why his way doesn't work. (Eg. because logically it *seems* like 5x20%=100% but it's really not.)

Comment: i agree with Roddy ;) as i guess this will be a bit complicated for him since he are not able to see easy stuffs like border/ white-space

Comment: `it also has default padding` --> and especially border because he already removed the padding

Comment: Thanks! My question is solved by this! You solved me a headache :)

Comment: OK guys, it is updated now, just need a little time to write it.